# Desaturate and blur <canvas> tag contents possible w/ javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible using javascript/jquery to desaturate and also blur a  tag contents where both effects are minimal in the center and max'd at the corners radially?

I have a canvas element with a parallax effect going on as you move the cursor around.  I want to blur and desaturate the contents the farther from the center of the container (div or canvas) but still allow the parallax effect to go on underneath... how can I create this effect?

Comment: is it even possible to apply both these effects in realtime anyhow?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in functionality for doing exactly what you want, but you do have the option of coding something to do this or using an existing library to give you similar functionality. With the HTML 5 canvas, you can alter images at the pixel level using javascript. Here's some reference:

[Pixel Manipulation by Beej](http://beej.us/blog/2010/02/html5s-canvas-part-ii-pixel-manipulation/)

[A few interesting blur techniques](http://www.flother.com/blog/2010/image-blur-html5-canvas/)

[JS Library that includes blurring and desaturating](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/)

Comment: this is basically a radial gradient mask applied to both a desaturation and blur effect filters... no idea where to begin with this one tho, any ideas?